# Adding objects to array that is a property of custom object

Tags: objective-c, arrays, ios8, xcode6

I have an app with two custom classes(vehicle & service records).  When a vehicle gets created it is added to a table view and when that cell is selected the vehicle is passed forward as a property to view controllers that reside in a tabbar controller.  One of the tabs is a table view that will have service records.  To create a record you select a bar button item that opens another view controller in which to add the record.

Vehicle.h

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *serviceRecordsArray;
```

Vehicle.m init

```
self.serviceRecordsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

FirstTableViewController prepareForSegue

```
TabbarViewController *tabController = segue.destinationViewController;

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
self.rowSelected = [indexPath row];

tabController.vehicle = [self.vehicleArray objectAtIndex:self.rowSelected];
tabController.vehicleAtIndex = self.rowSelected;
tabController.vehicleArray = self.vehicleArray;
```

TabbarViewController.h

```
@property Vehicle *vehicle;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger vehicleAtIndex; 
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *vehicleArray;

@property (nonatomic, strong) ProfileViewController *profileVC;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ServiceTableViewController *serviceTableVC;
```

TabbarViewController viewDidLoad

```
UINavigationController *navController = self.viewControllers[0];
self.profileVC = [[navController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
self.profileVC.vehicle = self.vehicle;
self.profileVC.vehicleAtIndex = self.vehicleAtIndex;
self.profileVC.vehicleArray = self.vehicleArray;

UINavigationController *navController2 = self.viewControllers[1];
self.serviceTableVC = [[navController2 viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
self.serviceTableVC.vehicle = self.vehicle;
self.serviceTableVC.vehicleAtIndex = self.vehicleAtIndex;
self.serviceTableVC.vehicleArray = self.vehicleArray;
```

profileVC and serviceTablevc.h

```
@property Vehicle *vehicle;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger vehicleAtIndex;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *vehicleArray;
```

AddRecordViewController.h

```
@property Vehicle *vehicle;
```

AddRecordViewController.m prepareForSegue

```
Service *serviceRecord = [[Service alloc] init];
serviceRecord.serviceType = self.serviceTypeTextfield.text;
serviceRecord.serviceDescription = self.serviceDescriptionTextfield.text;
[self.vehicle.serviceRecordsArray addObject:serviceRecord];
```

The serviceRecordsArray is a mutable array from my vehicle class that I want to place the records in before I save the vehicle to the file system.  The problem is that it is aways nill, because I’m not initializing a vehicle. I can’t initialize it because I need to be able to add to to it each time a record is added.  How can I have a array in my vehicle class and add to it when the vehicle is passed around as a property.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can’t initialize it because I need to be able to add to it"?  If you don't initialize it, the object doesn't exist and adding to it is impossible.

Comment: I can initialize it in the object's initializer, but when the vehicle is passed as a property the array is no longer initialized.

Comment: In that case, there may be something wrong with how it's being passed.  What does that code look like?

Comment: Edited: added remaining code

Comment: Should I assume that `serviceTablevc` also has a `prepareForSegue` that forwards the `Vehicle` to the `AddRecordViewController`?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Two possibilities come to mind.  One is, add `NSLog` statements everywhere you use `self.vehicle` to see where it's unexpectedly nil.  I'll put the other suggestion in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where the specific error is but the whole structure has become complex enough that I suggest you take a different approach.  Instead of passing data among view controllers, create an object to manage your data model and let the controllers use it when they need it.

I would create a singleton that maintains the vehicle array and knows which is the currently-selected vehicle.  When a controller wants to update the current vehicle's properties, it tells the data model to do so.  When a new vehicle is selected (or created), it happens within the data model.  When a controller wants to display vehicle properties, it gets the current state from the data model.

This approach reduces the dependencies between controllers and simplifies their implementation.  (E.g.: A controller that doesn't need vehicle details doesn't need to keep a reference solely to pass it to a different controller.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I only wish I fully understood how to implement all of that.

Comment: Here's a link where I answered someone else with **very simple** sample code for getting started in that direction.  They were using recipes instead of vehicles but the structure might give you an understanding of the principle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744454/pushing-data-through-uitableviewcell-with-unwind-segues/27745042#27745042